# How to create a merchant and customer registration in blazor with identity server?

Tags: blazor, identityserver4, blazor-webassembly

I'm looking to add 2 separate types of registrations to my blazor app. One for a merchant to sign up and one for a customer to sign up. but for the life of me I cannot find an example on how this can be done. Is there any way this can be done?

Edit:
Reason for this is that they have different fields that I want the user to fill in.

Comment: why not create two different endpoints and using the frontend to differentiate between which type of user is registering and call the api

Comment: @supernerd didnt think of that as i was focused on doing it in one proejct as it is a blazor web assembly app that is hosted with asp net core. is it possible to have 2 api's for a blazor web assembly app that is hosted with asp net core?